# Unity 3d particles not showing in game view

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

When I drag and drop a particle prefab into scene it shows on the scene view and also shows in the game view

But when I maximize the game view all particles turn off

How can I fix that?

Comment: You probably did not activate play on start

Comment: I did its stop shiwnig when i maximum the game view im using urp project

Comment: Can you show us some screenshots. It is difficult to solve a visual error without some visuals

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about particle system bug :V, you can use this link to fix your problem

[Link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1358918/particle-system-not-showing-up-in-game-view-showin.html)